# Derive right from left?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: So What steps were took to get before the red equation to after?]

So I'm dumbfounded by this question and want to dispel any uncertainties.

Comment: Are you asking perhaps about multiplying by $1=\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{x-1}}{\dfrac{x}{x-1}}$?

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{1-x}{x}}{(x-1)\cdot B} = \frac{1-x}{x(x-1)\cdot B} = \frac{-1}{x\cdot B}$$ since $\frac{1-x}{x-1} = -1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps.
$$\begin{align}\frac{\frac{1-x}{x}}{(x-1)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}+1\right)}&=\frac{1}{(x-1)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}+1\right)}\cdot \frac{1-x}{x}\\&=\frac{1}{\color{red}{(x-1)}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}+1\right)}\cdot\frac{-\color{red}{(x-1)}}{x}\\&=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}+1\right)}\cdot\frac{-1}{x}\end{align}$$

Comment: Since im new here, whats the point of badges and stuff?? are there physical rewards?

Comment: @Mathisthethoughtofcreation Gaining reputation by asking and answering questions gives you some [privileges](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) on the website. Badges are just for fun. (They're like videogame achievements, if you are familiar with those.)

Comment: @AustinMohr: I like your explanation:)